# gwt server not found after deployment

Tags: gwt, server-error

I've a strange problem. I created the plain vanilla Greetings example with the webAppCreator of gwt. That means I created a project called Test and after that I did not modify it in any way. Then I created a war file with "ant war" and deployed this on my local tomcat 7. The server starts fine and the Grettings page is loaded properly. But, when clicking on the Send button I get the following error:

[image]

There a no error messages in the tomcat logs. However in the development mode the stuff works fine. I'm using gwt 2.5. Any idea what could cause this problem?

Edit: Maybee this gives some further insights:
[image]

I found a stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/server/GreetingServiceImpl : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.server.GreetingServiceImpl)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2908)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:461)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

But what does it mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the problem.

The error UnsupportedClassVersionError means that I tried to run a compiled java file with an older runtime, i.e. I compiled the servlets with java 7 and tried to run them with java 6.

I repaired this by setting the correct JAVA_HOME path to my .bash_profiles file like this

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java_7/Home
```

That was it, now everything runs fine. Thanks for reading anyway.